# Solr sorting with tf too high

Tags: solr

I came with this problem, when I search "James", the doc title with many "james" rank top, for example, doc title "James James James...", while it's not a good doc, how can I demote this condition in the requested url?

Comment: it always gives docs with more occurrence of the searched query to the top order in result. if you want some doc not to come in the top order of result, you should use elevator component.

Comment: https://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrRelevancyFAQ might be a good place to start.  There is a section on "demoting" some part of the score (although it's counter-intuitive).  There are lots of ways to slice and dice search results / relevancy - perhaps you want to NOT include titles in your search, or score other things much higher...  Write back with more specifics and perhaps I can help suggest a way to get the results you need.

Comment: Also - before worrying about what the url would look like, you may want to do your testing/experimenting in the Admin UI - it goes faster usually...

Comment: @vinod, thank you for you answer firstly, I still want to use the default ranker, so the elevator may not suitable，also the docs are huge, I must choose some features or rules.

Comment: @jb62, thank you for you answer firstly, sorry, the last time I may not be clear, I use q=title:James to search,  so ... Maybe I need to design a new class as a ranker，not use default, which can't be satisfied by just modifying request url. Oh, it needs much work.